# Iterate through Json list object - Python

Tags: python, json, loops, python-3.x, object

I have some JSON text I want to iterate through, formatted in the following way:

```
{
  "itemsPerPage": 45,
  "links": {
    "next": "https://www.12345.com"
  },
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "333333",
      "placeID": "63333",
      "description": " ",
      "displayName": "test-12345",
      "name": "test",
      "status": "Active",
      "groupType": "Creative",
      "groupTypeV2": "Public",
      "memberCount": 1,
    },
     {
      "id": "32423",
      "placeID": "606",
      "description": " ",
      "displayName": "test123",
      "name": "test",
      "status": "Active",
      "groupType": "Creative",
      "groupTypeV2": "Private",
      "memberCount": 1,
    },
```

I am trying to iterate through this list, and grab the displayName, however my code won't recognize all of the different display names. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(json_obj['list'])):
if (json_obj['list'][i]['displayName'] == "some id"):
    do stuff
else:
    exit()
```

How can I fix the statement, in order to successfully loop through the json obj?

Comment: This is not a valid json object.

Comment: what makes it not a valid obj?

Comment: How can I use this obj, to iterate through and find display name?

Comment: Why are you referring to it as `json_obj` and `dataset`? Are those two variables the same?

Comment: See [here](http://jsonlint.com/) why this is not a valid JSON object

Comment: yes, I changed up some var names. sorry.

Comment: This a snippet of the full JSON text, which I validated and is a valid object.

Comment: You exit the whole interpreter after the first time the if statement fails... do you really intend to completely cut off the script with this if statement? also... indentation.... pls fix ;)

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I'm not letting the if statment iterate through the object. How can I check for if i have reached the end, and ID is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the JSON you posted isn't valid, I'll assume you left some stuff off the end.

```
for entry in dataset['list']:
    print(entry['displayName'])
```

Will loop through your JSON data.

If you want to do_stuff() if it matches a certain value:

```
for entry in dataset['list']:
    if entry['displayName'] == 'test-12345':
        do_stuff()
```

Comment: is entry just a random variable?

Comment: Yes - I'm looping through every object in dataset['list'] - on each loop, the current object is named 'entry'. You can call it anything you want.

Comment: @pokemongirl1234 Yes. He chose the name entry because each object inside list is an entry.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me.

```
import json
text = """{
  "itemsPerPage": 45,
  "links": {
    "next": "https://www.12345.com"
  },
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "333333",
      "placeID": "63333",
      "description": " ",
      "displayName": "test-12345",
      "name": "test",
      "status": "Active",
      "groupType": "Creative",
      "groupTypeV2": "Public",
      "memberCount": 1
    },
     {
      "id": "32423",
      "placeID": "606",
      "description": " ",
      "displayName": "test",
      "name": "test",
      "status": "Active",
      "groupType": "Creative",
      "groupTypeV2": "Private",
      "memberCount": 1
    }]}"""
data = json.loads(text)
for item in data['list']:
    if 'displayName' in item:
        print(item['displayName'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually perform actions within your loop. Python relies on whitespace to denote blocks. This is something you can't forget when writing Python.

```
for i in range(len(json_obj['list'])):
if (json_obj['list'][i]['displayName'] == "some id"):
    do stuff
else:
    exit()
```

should be

```
for i in range(len(json_obj['list'])):
    if (json_obj['list'][i]['displayName'] == "some id"):
        do stuff
    else:
        exit()
```